# What is the top speed of the twin seat Hawker Hunter?

Tags: aircraft-performance, hawker-hunter

Recently I learnt that [the Hawker Hunter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawker_Hunter) had a side-by-side twin seat trainer version. This is unusual, since more often the tandem configuration is used. I'm sure the engineers had a good reason to choose this solution, but it got me wondering: how much is the top speed impacted by the resulting increase in frontal area?

From what I've found online, the specs are the same for both trainer and single-seat versions but that doesn't seem right; if nothing else, the empty weight should be different. Is there a former Hawker Hunter pilot here who trained on the twin seater and can tell us the truth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manufacturer](https://www.baesystems.com/en/heritage/hawker-hunter)
lists over half a dozen variants of Hunter two-seaters.
You probably mean the T.7.

For a fair comparison, its closest single seat variant is the F.6, 
maximum speed [Mach 0.94](http://www.airpowerworld.info/jet-fighter-planes/hawker-hunter-mk58a.htm)
(715 mph) at sea level.

The T.7A, a T.7 with different instruments, has a maximum speed of
[Mach 0.92](http://www.airpowerworld.info/trainers/hawker-hunter-t7-trainer-plane.htm) (690 mph) at 36,000 ft.

So the T.7 is a few per cent slower than the F.6.
But it's no slowpoke: in 1959 it even [won](http://yorkshireairmuseum.org/exhibits/cold-war-aircraft/hawker-hunter-t7/)
the flying leg of a complicated race against 200 other [entries](https://forums.autosport.com/topic/65066-1959-daily-mail-paris-to-london-race/).

Your empty-weight test suggests that these numbers are trustworthy:  the weights posted there say that the T.7 is 762 pounds (5 per cent) heavier.